# Converting dvd to MKV videos, anything wrong here?

Tags: mplayer, mencoder

I'm converting DVD media to a MKV format video with mencoder:

`mencoder dvd://4 -o output.mkv -oac mp3lame -ovc x264 -x264encopts crf=20:8x8dct:frameref=4:bframes=3:b_pyramid=normal:weight_b`

But the output from `file output.mkv` indicate it's AVI format ?

`RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 720 x 576, 25.00 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)`

Answer (score 2):

The output format isn't set automatically, you need an `-of` option.

At least in the version of `mencoder` that I use, there is no `-of mkv`, so I create an AVI file, and then use `mkvmerge` to convert (and mux the additional channels):

```
mencoder -of avi -o temp_en.avi -oac ... -ovc ... -alang en -slang en -vobsubout temp_en dvd://4
mencoder -of avi -o temp_de.avi -oac ... -ovc frameno -alang de -slang de -vobsubout temp_de dvd://4
mkvmerge -o output.mkv --lang 1:eng temp_en.avi --lang 1:ger -D temp_de.avi --lang 0:eng temp_en.idx --lang 0:ger temp_de.idx
```

These are from memory, so may not work exactly as posted.